# how to input a tensor of shape (10000,299,299,1) to inceptionv3 model in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a pre-trained model of inceptionv3 in keras with tensorflow backend.

I have a training dataset of 10,000 images of size (299,299) (they are gray scale). I converted it to the input shape for tensorflow as (10000,299,299,1). When I tried to fit the inceptionv3 model I am getting an error as

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, none, none, 3) but got array with shape (10000, 299, 299, 1)

I tried to change the input shape of the tensor by using

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(299,299,1))
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_tensor = input_tensor)
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 32 for 'Assign_376' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [3,3,1,32], [32,3,3,3].

Could someone please help me solve this? My dataset is grayscale. and I am clueless how to input a grayscale dataset to inceptionv3 in keras using tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the pre-trained weights, you can't simply change the depth to 1 and expect it to work. This is because your first layer of convolutional filters have a depth of 3. You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668771/can-we-use-the-weights-of-a-model-trained-on-rgb-images-for-grayscale-images/44670599#44670599) for some idea of what can be done.

What that error is saying is that your first layer weights after editing have a shape of `[3, 3, 1, 32]`, which means a 3x3 convolution filter with depth 1 and 32 sets of these filters. However, the original model was `[32, 3, 3, 3]`, which means a 3x3 convolution fliter with depth 3 and 32 sets of these filters. You have to solve 2 problems here:

1. Change the depth to 3 and add another layer before this to deal with depth 1, or refer to the post I referenced above for some options to solve this.
2. Ensure that the shapes of the weights are indexed in the same manner. There are some indexing issues from your `ValueError`.