# Keras input_tensor shape for transfer learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am running a CNN for classification of medical scans using Keras and transfer learning with imagenet and InceptionV3. I am building the model with some practice data of size `X_train = (624, 128, 128, 1)` and `Y_train = (624, 2)`.

I am trying to resize the `input_tensor` to suit the shape of my images (128 x 128 x 1) using the below code.

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1)) 
base_model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=input_tensor,weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
```

Doing this I get a value error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 32. Shapes 
are [3,3,1,32] and [32,3,3,3]. for 'Assign_753' (op: 'Assign') with input 
shapes: [3,3,1,32], [32,3,3,3]
```

Is there a way to allow this model to accept my images in their format?

Edit: 
For what its worth, here is the code to generate the training data.

```
X = []
Y = []
for subj, subj_slice in slices.items():
    # X.extend([s[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] for s in slice])
    subj_slice_norm = [((imageArray - np.min(imageArray)) / np.ptp(imageArray)) for imageArray in subj_slice]
    X.extend([s[ :, :, np.newaxis] for s in subj_slice_norm])
    subj_status = labels_df['deadstatus.event'][labels_df['PatientID'] == subj]
    subj_status = np.asanyarray(subj_status)
    #print(subj_status)
    Y.extend([subj_status] * len(subj_slice))

X = np.stack(X, axis=0)
Y = to_categorical(np.stack(Y, axis=0))]

n_samp_train = int(X.shape[0]*0.8)
X_train, Y_train = X[:n_samp_train], Y[:n_samp_train]
```

Edit2: 
I think the other alternative would be to take my X which is shape `(780, 128, 128, 1)`, clone each of the 780 images and append two as dummies. Is this possible? Resulting in `(780, 128, 128, 3)`.

Comment: From [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/applications/#inceptionv3): "[input tensor] should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 139". Therefore you need to resize (or pad) your input images first and then feed them to the model. And for the channels you can replicate it two times but I am not sure whether it does negatively affect accuracy or not.

Comment: There are some solutions offered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670599/2099607), but I am not sure if they are suitable to medical images as well. At the end, you should try and see the results.

Comment: Replicate the channel two times - I was thinking along those lines myself. Makes sense. Is there a straight forward way to do this, perhaps by modifying my X variable directly. Or should it be done earlier, when collecting the images to be brought into the IDE?

Comment: You can either use [`tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) or [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) from numpy: `X = np.repeat(X, 3, axis=-1)` or `X = np.tile(X, (1, 1, 1, 3))`.

Comment: Perfect. That is exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware of np.repeat Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the existing keras layers to convert the existing image shape to the expected shape for the pre-trained model rather than using the numpy for replicating channels. As replicating channels before training may consume 3x the memory, but integrating this processing at runtime will save up a lot of memory.

You can proceed this way.

**Step 1:** Create a Keras Model that converts your input images to the shape that can be fed as the input for the base_model as follows:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import RepeatVector, Input, Reshape

inputs = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))
reshaped1 = Reshape(target_shape=((128 * 128 * 1,)))(inputs)
repeated = RepeatVector(n=3)(reshaped1)
reshaped2 = Reshape(target_shape=(3, 128, 128))(repeated)
input_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=reshaped2)
```

**Step 2:** Define pre-trained model **InceptionV3** as follows:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=input_model.output, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

**Step 3:** Combine both the models as follows:

```
combined_model = Model(inputs=input_model.input, outputs=base_model.output)
```

The advantage of this method is that the keras model itself will take care of the image processing stuff like channel replication at runtime. Thus, we need not replicate the image channels by ourselves with numpy and the results will be memory efficient.